# How to generate native end-of-line (EOL) characters from js in browser

Tags: javascript

I would like to generate a text file in JS in the browser and let the user to download it. How do I generate the text content with native end-of-line characters (e.g., '\n', '\r\n')?

Comment: If it's being done in the browser, they don't have to download it.  It's already there.  Why don't you just write it to the HTML window with instructions on how to cut-and-paste?

Comment: @TimRoberts That's a good point, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to have something that works 100%, and this is by design as what kind of operating system the user is running is considered private data.

One option is to use `window.navigator.userAgent` and check if the string has `win` somewhere (case insensitive); note however that what is the value of this string is highly variable and the user can even change and put there whatever wants.

Even in default configurations the content of this string seems weird (for example I'm on a linux system but the string in my case contains ALSO parts referring to Apple things `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`).

<strike>One sad part of this is that (IMO) microsoft deliberately choose to use `\r\n` as newline to create compatibility problems. In a perfect world they would be charged for the cost the whole community had to pay for this absurd and deliberate action.</strike>

After double-checking the historic timeline this doesn't seem to be the case at all. CP/M was popular and the choice was there so basically MS/DOS just wanted to be compatible with that.

Now it seems (at least to me... and NOW!) that using a sequence of two characters to end the lines of a text file "in source" is a very questionable idea (what you send to say a printing device is a different thing, and does actually make sense), but I can't exclude that someone could honestly think back then that it would have been a good idea.

Comment: Nonsense.  Microsoft did not invent this by any means.  MS-DOS inherited CR/LF from CP/M which in turn inherited it from the DEC VAX.  Unix was the outlier for choosing LF.  (Of course, Microsoft did not actually invent MS-DOS either, but that's another story.)

Comment: @TimRoberts: true... I checked out history after writing this post, and I'm going to strike out that section. Never attribute to malice what could be explained by stupidity.
Truth remains that up to about 2000 windows was IMO actively creating problems to portable software... (or at least that was my perception in a number of different occasions; my explanation back then was sort of trying to lock-in programmers).
Only saw some sign of change around that time.